# replace separate parts of a string in R

Tags: r, string

`substring() <- value` or `substr() <- value` can only replace a single character range per word. I wonder what the best solution is if I want to replace several disjoint characters in a string. My current solution looks like this.

```
string <- "a string"
splitted <- strsplit(string,"",T)[[1]]
splitted[c(1,5,8)] <- c("that", "", "ks")
paste(splitted, collapse="")
[1] "that stinks"
```

Of course, this is a random example. I actually want to replace nucleotides in genes at hundred of separate positions. Note that single characters (bases) would always be replaced by single characters, as opposed to my example here.

Alternatively I could call `substr() <- value` successively in a loop (I don't think I could avoid a loop if I used `substr()` since I would need to process the previous result several times), but that would probably be slower.

Thanks for the suggestions.

EDIT : my example was misleading, here is my test function

```
replaceCharsInString <-function(string, positions, replacement) {
    splitted <- strsplit(string,"",T)[[1]]
    splitted[positions] <- replacement   #'replacement' is a character vector
    paste(splitted,collapse="")
}

> replaceCharsInString("ACCTTTAAGAGATTTAGGGAGA", c(2,5,7), c("G","C","C"))
[1] "AGCTCTCAGAGATTTAGGGAGA"
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand what you are looking for exactly since you even say your example doesn't represent what you are actually doing.

May be possible by using `()` also called a capturing group:

```
gsub("(.*)(this)(.*)", '\\1him\\3', 'get this off my desk')
[1] "get him off my desk"
```

The parentheses create groups. `R` can then reference the captured group numbers using the double back slash notation: `\\1`, `\\2`, etc. Here I have 3 groups

1. `get`
2. `this`
3. `off my desk`

In my code, I am replacing `this` (group 2) with `him`.

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain what I'm looking for.

Comment: That doesn't do what I describe in my edited question. I need to replace characters at specific positions, regardless of the characters themselves. I need to replace the characters at position x, regardless of whether it's an "A", "C" or "G" or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

After finishing this, maybe my way is more complicated, but here we go:

```
f <- function(x, strings, replaces){
  e <- new.env()
  e$x <- x
  if(length(strings)!=length(replaces)) print("Strings should have the same number of elements as replaces") else {

  foo2 <- function(i){
  e$x <- gsub(strings[i], replaces[i], e$x)
}
lapply(1:length(strings), foo2)

}
return(e$x)
}


string <- "a string"
strings <- c("a", "r", "ng")
replaces <- c("that", "", "nks")


f(string, strings, replaces)


[1] "that stinks"
```

Comment: I ultimately want to provide a string, a vector of indices indicating which characters I want to replace, and the replacement characters as a vector. Your example works because the pattern to replace contains unique elements, but I'm not sure it would solve my problem (I want to mutate genes by replacing bases that are often the same, but at different positions in the strings).